# Converting NSData back to Audio File

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, nsdata, avaudiorecorder

i have converted my `.caf` audio file to `NSData` object using the following line of code:

`NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[MyRecorderFilePathURL path] options: 
0 error:&err];`

I am doing so to upload the binary object to a server through a web service.
How do i convert **audioData** back to a `.caf` file which can be played using `AVAudioPlayer`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AVAudioPlayer has a method for playing sound from NSData object .
You can use

`- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)outError`  method of AVAudioPlayer

Comment: thanks. this serves the purpose! but is there a way to convert nsdata object to an audio file?

Comment: NSData has method for this.. writeToURL:atomically: you can give file name with extension caf

Comment: @Ali3n this doesn't work in my scenario - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385705/iphone-nsdata-representation-of-audio-file-for-editing Could you please help me out! Thanks.

Comment: ...because of this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394630/iphone-editing-audio-files-header-and-footer it didn't work!