# How to read sound file from sqlite database

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, avfoundation

In my application,i want to use so many sound file using sqlite database.I googles lots .All says use blob.Can any one help me to code for reading Audio file from sqlite database?thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know how to get ANY data out of the database?  What have you tried?  What in particular is giving you trouble?

Comment: I know how to get data from db.and i doesn know how to access audio file from db tats the problem @HotLicks

Comment: Have you looked at the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html)?  In particular the [C function list](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html)?  You essentially just use the blob version of the same methods you'd use for other data (though read the notes, since you need to get the length).

Answer (score 0):

You can download the audio file as an NSData and then load it into AVAudioPlayer

```
-(id)initWithData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)outError
```

[Answer taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157916/converting-nsdata-back-to-audio-file)